# What are some type-level TypeScript libraries?

Tags: typescript

To learn about the TS ecosystem, I'm looking for examples of type-level TS libraries.

By 'type-level TS library', I mean something like an npm package that does *not* provide typings for a specific value-level library, but instead provides facilities for type-level programming.

Some examples of this sort of thing:

- [fp-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/) has higher-kinded-types
- [utility-types](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types) is 'lodash for types'
- There's a library for testing types using types only (can't remember the name)

What are more examples of type-level TS libraries?

This is an objective question and I'm genuinely trying to learn something. I am not asking for 'good' vs. 'bad', just examples.

Comment: @snakecharmerb, il_raffa, GPhilo, halfter, Makyen, you put the question on hold because it asks for a recommendation. 


Could you please re-read the question, specifically the part where I wrote "I am not asking for 'good' vs. 'bad', just examples". 

Also please notice that there is no spam or opinionated discussion. The moderation in this case is removing value from the site rather than contributing.

Comment: Please don't add voting commentary to questions - it is not interesting to most readers, who do not either sign in or vote. I am quite sure this is off-topic based on my understanding of the posting guidelines, but you are most welcome to raise it on _Meta Stack Overflow_ (if you do so please ping me here, and I will see if I can chip in).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some honorable mentions:

#### Types

- [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest) A collection of essential TypeScript types
- [ts-essentials](https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials) All basic TypeScript types in one place
- [typescript-conditional-types](https://github.com/LeDDGroup/typescript-conditional-types) Helpers for typescript generic types
- [ts-types-utils](https://github.com/LeDDGroup/ts-types-utils) Type utilities for typescript
- [type-zoo](https://github.com/pelotom/type-zoo) A menagerie of useful type operators for TypeScript
- [unionize](https://github.com/pelotom/unionize) Boilerplate-free functional sum types in TypeScript
- [hkts](https://github.com/pelotom/hkts) A simple encoding of higher-kinded types in TypeScript
- [safe-units](https://github.com/jscheiny/safe-units) Type-safe TypeScript units of measure
- [type-plus](https://github.com/unional/type-plus) Additional types and types adjusted utilities for TypeScript

#### Test own Types with Types

- [is](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is) Type check values
- [conditional-type-checks](https://github.com/dsherret/conditional-type-checks) Types for testing TypeScript types.

#### Transformers

- [ts-transformer-keys](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys)