# Make union type of objects from type keys

Tags: typescript

How can I create a type `DESIRED_RESULT` starting from `INITIAL`.

from:

```
export type INITIAL = {
  aa: boolean,
  bb: string,
  cc: number[],
};
```

to:

```
export type DESIRED_RESULT =
{ aa: boolean } |
{ bb: string } |
{ cc: number[] };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[utility-types](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types) has [`Unionize`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types/blob/master/src/mapped-types.ts#L350) that does exactly that:

```
export type Unionize<T extends object> = {
  [P in keyof T]: { [Q in P]: T[P] }
}[keyof T];

type DESIRED_RESULT = Unionize<INITIAL>
```

Comment: @AndreElrico: yep, check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58338490/what-are-some-type-level-typescript-libraries